# Migraciones directas aCpanel

Tags: mysql, laravel, cpanel

Es que estoy aprendiendo a crear una aplicacion de Laravel, y quiero usar migraciones, pero no desde el XAMM o el WAMP si no directamente al cpanel que tengo, en una base de datos de prueba, en producción.

se supone que ya puse las credenciales en el `.env` pero sigo sin poder crear la migracion ¿Como configurar el `.env` para producción? ¿Es error de mi cpanel o falta de configuracion?.

Estoy aprendiendo con la version de Laravel 8.12.3

**Este es el error:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**y asi tengo configurado en `.env`: (son credenciales de ejemplo las deje para que vean como lo tengo configurado!!!!)**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y cuál es el error? Fuera de tema pero.. ¿estás aprendiendo con laravel 4?

Comment: Bueno en consola de comando en el proyecto le doy:  "laravel -v"   me dice "Laravel Installer 4.0.5" pero si ejecuto el proyecto en la pagina principal dice "Laravel v8.12.3" la intale ayer asi que se que es la ultima

Comment: agregare un pantallaso del error y cambiare la pregunta con lo de la version

Comment: listo ya lo modifique y quedo mejor

Comment: jajajaja no las publique las cambie, obviamente se lo que debo mostrar, solo deje las credenciales de ejemplo

Comment: El error es simple, revisa tu php.ini si tienes habilitado o no la extensión de mysql. Si lo tienes habilitado y sigue dando error, entonces debes instalar dicha extensión.

Comment: Bueno puede ser un error simple pero como no conozco del tema no he podido encontrar ese archivo php.ini ¿Esta en el proyecto o en el cpanel? en caso de estar en el cpanel ¿Donde lo hallo? Gracias

Comment: Ve al File Manager de tu cPanel y dentro de public_html encontrarás dicho archivo